# Convert Date format of BASH to Date Format of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bash, shell, date, curl

On executing `date` command in linux shell the format of date dispplayed is `Wed Oct 21 11:48:18 IST 2015`

On executing the `date` command in Javascript the format displayed is `Wed Oct 21 2015 11:48:18 GMT+0530 (IST)`

Using shell script how can I convert linux shell date format to javascript date format and use it for a command to post data using `CURL`

Comment: look at `man date` to get a custom formatted output

Comment: There is no "javascript date format". There are some string formats that are [*specified for parsing*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.parse), however none are reliable across multiple implementations. If you are concerned with only one, you may be able to use a particular format. There's only one standardised format for output strings: [*toISOString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring). Some implementations support [*ECMA-402*](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-402.htm) for formatting output.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it using the command `date "+%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (%Z)"` and the output comes as `Wed Oct 21 2015 12:22:44 GMT+0530 (IST)`